# How to create autoincrement integer field in TypeORM migration?

Tags: mysql, database, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I design a table and want an integer autoincrement column for an ID.
For sure, I read the docs about `isGenerated` param for migrations.

Now, my code looks like this:

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {

        await queryRunner.createTable(
            new Table({
                name: tableName,

                columns: [
                    {
                        name: "id",
                        type: "int",
                        isGenerated: true,
                        isPrimary: true,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "seller_id",
                        type: "int"
                    }
                ]
            })
      )
}
```

But as a result, I got: [image: WorkBench]

As you can see, `id` is not flagged as `AI`. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
    name: "id",
    type: "int",
    isPrimary: true,
    isGenerated: true,
    generationStrategy: "increment"
 },
```

available options:

```
generationStrategy?: "uuid" | "increment" | "rowid" | "identity";
```